# User sees all Sharepoint document as being from 1938

Tags: sharepoint-2007, user-profile

I currently have a problem I was unable to solve concerning Sharepoint.
One of our user is seeing every file on Sharepoint as being from around 1938.
The Created and Last Modified field are affected.
When the user saves a file on his computer, the date is correct.

If I log on his computer, the date are fine.
If he log on my computer, the date are wrong once again, so it is linked to its Sharepoint account.

The day and month are wrong to, but files uploaded 3 days apart are still 3 days apart for him.
I don't see how anything could affect a date like that...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

PS: Destroying his account and give him a new one is not a solution for now. He has been in this company for a long time and he has a lot of rights inherited from Sharepoint 2003 that are complicated to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would check is the user's "region" settings. A user can set a time zone and calendar type to be whatever they want, and it overrides the settings from the web application. Some of the calendar types do change the date to match up with whatever calendar system is chosen.

To change the regional settings for a user:

- Click the user's name in the top navbar
- Click the "my settings" link
- Click the "my regional settings" link
- Check the "Time Zone" and "Calendar" settings
- Better yet, check the "always follow web settings" checkbox at the top of the page